# Why is it Euler's 'Totient' Function?

Tags: number-theory, terminology, math-history

The function $\phi(n)$ calculates the number of positive integers $k \leqslant n \space , \gcd(k,n)=1$. It was found by mathematician **Leonhard Euler**. In 1879, mathematician **J.J.Sylvester** coined the term **'totient'** function. What is the meaning of the word **'totient'** in the context? Why was the name coined for the function?

I have received replies that 'tot' refers to 'that many, so many' in Latin. What about the suffix 'ient'? It can be seen in words such as 'quotient' etc. Finally isn't there any reference to 'relatively prime numbers' ?

Comment: The [History of Science and Mathematics Stack Exchange](http://hsm.stackexchange.com) seems like a better place for this question.

Comment: This has an answer at https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23694/where-does-the-word-totient-come-from

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Latin *tot* is correct as an origin for the root, but the suffix '-iens' doesn't originate with Sylvester either who was undoubtedly thinking of the already fully-formed word [*totiens*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/totiens#Latin) when he coined 'totient.' Compare this to how [*quotiens*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quotiens#Latin) enters into English as 'quotient.'

Sylvester knew Latin well enough that he would have been aware of the parallel between *totiens* and *quotiens*, which is actually a very manifest parallel since they function together as correlative conjunctions. A clause will introduce *quotiens* - how often; the next clause will answer *totiens* - this often.

ex:
*quotiens doces, totiens disce.* 'Learn as often as you teach.' (literally, 'as often as you teach, learn this often.')

Correlative conjunctions like this are common in Latin.
Here's another you'll recognize:

*quantum* - how much, *tantum* - this much.

Anyway, it seems to me that the word totient is meant to refer to the abstract notion of saying 'here is how many there are.' It doesn't seem to reference the quality of being relatively prime or any other quality.

(But speaking of 'qualities,' there's also *qualis* - what kind, *talis* - this kind, which hopefully goes to show how common these *q-t* correlatives are.)

Answer (score 4):

It comes from the Latin *tot*--"that many, so many" (as in "total").

Comment: I'm guessing that totient = tot + ient where tot refers to what you said and ient, to the suffix such as quotient. Where is the source for this answer?

Answer (score 4):

Going with a similar word: [quotient](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=quotient)

quotiens (how many times) = quot (how many) + tiens (times)

If totient has a similar origin, than it would mean "that many times" or "all the times". It probably refers to "all the numbers" coprime with $n$.

In latin "totus" means "all" or "whole" - see under the IE root [teuta-](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/indoeurop.html#IR116300)

Comment: (+1) from me. However, is there any connection with relatively prime numbers and his etymology?

Comment: Not as far as I can tell. The name "totient" doesn't seem to refer specifically to relative prime numbers. It is not something like "coprime totient function".

Answer (score 2):

The word totient is made from two latin words,” tot”, meaning  so much, as many, or more archaically from  the word “totum”,  meaning whole or total  (ref 1),  and a suffix “ient” meaning, more or less,  the process by which the desired  total is obtained.   That  process  is defined by the  ф (n) equation you  mentioned, and that is where the relatively prime instructions reside within the name Totient.
Ref 1   The Oxford Dictionary of Word Histories.  2002, pages 516-517  Oxford University Press

Answer (score 1):

I want to give a reference of [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23694/where-does-the-word-totient-come-from). I have searched the internet after seeing your question and I felt that I can't add anything new with this answer. So instead of copying, I can give you this reference; I hope this will help you.